# can I use partials in a for loop in ejs?

Tags: for-loop, ejs, partials

I'm trying to include partials in a for loop in EJS.

```
 <% let index = 1 %>
    <% for (let item in db) { %>

    <div class="box unfocused box_<%=index  %> ">
     <% if (db[item].type === "video") { %>
      <%- include ('partials/_video.ejs') %> 

    <% } else if (db[item].type === "collection") { %>   
      <%- include ('partials/_collection.ejs') %> 


    <% } else if (db[item].type === "box") { %>   
      <%- include ('partials/_box.ejs') %> 
     
      <% } %>

    </div>

    <% index ++ %>


    <% } %>
```

For some reason, the variables defined in the for loop are not being passed down into the partial. For example, `_video.ejs` looks like this:

```
      <video muted=true autoplay=true loop=true width="250">

        <source src="<%=db[item].src%>" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
```

When I run the code, the browser tells me that `item` is not defined in `_video.ejs` (`item` is defined in the for loop).

How to pass `item` down into the partial?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%for(let post of posts){%> 
    <%-include('_post',{post: post}); %>
<%}%>
```